# Invalid Hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Why is it throwing this error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my js which runs when SignUp button is clicked. I am providing Dispatch and Navigate hooks here. But I think the issue is in this class only

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { addUser } from "./userInfoSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";


const SubmitSignUpForm = (email,password,name) => {

const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
const navigate = useNavigate();

  axios.post("https://localhost:44336/api/signin/SignUpUser", {
    Name: name,
    Email: email,
    Password: password
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    dispatch(addUser(response));
    navigate("./Browse");
  })
  .catch((reason) => {
    console.log(reason);
  });
  
  }

  export default SubmitSignUpForm;
```

**I am getting this error and I think when I click the button, dispatch is making some kind of issue. any idea?**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a hook within a function, which is not allowed in react.

I modified your component to be a custom hook const `SubmitSignUpForm = (email,password,name) => {`

To fix your issue you need to create a custom hook which will allow you to call other hooks.

```js
// Destruct props
const useSubmitForm = ({
        email,
        password,
        name
    }) => {
        // You can also have useState hooks here and expose them if you want to keep 
        // your logic clean

        // Call your hooks
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const navigate = useNavigate();

        const submitFormHandler = () => {
            axios.post("https://localhost:44336/api/signin/SignUpUser", {
                    Name: name,
                    Email: email,
                    Password: password
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    // not sure where this addUser function is coming from
                    // your might have some other errors
                    dispatch(addUser(response));
                    navigate("./Browse");
                })
                .catch((reason) => {
                    console.log(reason);
                });

        }

        return {
            submitFormHandler
        }
```

No when you use it only in your react component you can do this

```js
// react component...
// assuming you have some state?
const [ firstName, setFirstName ] = useState(undefined)
const { submitFormHandler } = useSubmitForm({ name:firstName, //...others })

//Use your handler on a button 
<button onClick={submitFormHandler} > Submit </button>
```

Hooks are functions that "hook up" into the react life cycle, so they can be only used with `useSomething` keyword so react knows to hook them up

Comment: what is the difference? You have also called it in functional component right? So basically I need to change my function into a hook to fool React that now I can call my hook into a so called custom hook?

Comment: could u help? because we can use useState in functional component then why not dispatch?? @mssp

Comment: Yeah, but it does not mean it needs to be via a another hook. You can call hooks directly in your functional components. I suggest reading this to make it more clear https://react.dev/reference/rules/rules-of-hooks . You can use `useDispatch` as well. It is considered best practice to wrap your logic into a custom hook and use it in your view components

Comment: GOT it thanks... the other thing which I did to resolve it is, I called the hooks in my main Login component and passed those into this SignUp function... it also worked...